# Automate plotting horizontal bar chart in python grouped by a column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following dataframe:

```
ProgramID ProgramStartDate ProgramEndDate ProjectID ProjectStartDate ProjectEndDate
1113            8.794           9.345       101         8.7              8.98
1113            8.794           9.345       102         9.1              9.3
1114            23.3            34.5        103         25.3             37
```

I want to automate the plotting individual horizontal bar chart grouped by ProgramID. So basically from the above data I want to have two different bar charts one for 1113 and one for 1114. Not sure how to pull that off.

Explanation: ProgramID and ProjectID has parent-child relationship. A specific Project can start or end beyond the Start and End Date range.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ProgramID':['1113','1113','1114'],
    'ProgramStartDate':[8.794,8.794,23.3],
    'ProgramEndDate':[9.345,9.345,34.5],

})
df1 =df.tail(2)
df1
```

output:

```
ProgramID   ProgramStartDate    ProgramEndDate
  1113     8.794                  9.345
  1114     23.300                 34.500
```

and then:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# a simple line plot
df1.plot(kind='bar',x='ProgramID')
```

[image]